# Data exchange with legacy program

Tags: .net, excel, dde

One of our laboratories retrieves data from an old particle size analyzer program using, I believe, DDE.  The data is written to an Excel spreadsheet.  For instance, to retrieve the mean value (selmv), one cell's formula is

=mtwin|summarydata!selmv

I have read several posts that I should not try to use DDE (nor the free library NDde) with .NET.

How should I retrieve this and other data from this program using .NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NDde worked well with this MTWIN program and was simple to implement.  Thanks to [Brian Gideon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/158779/brian-gideon) for this excellent library.